# Why browsers block specific URL via safebrowsing but safebrowsing API don't say URL is dangerous?

Tags: safe-browsing, safe-browsing-api

Currently I implementing google safe browsing on my web service to filter dangerous URL. When I was testing some specific malicious URL, I find out that browsers which using `fullHashes:find` API method detects some specific URL as dangerous, but `threatMatches:find` with all possible threat types and platforms says that same URL is safe. I preprocessed this URL as google safebrowsing doc says, and find out that my local database acquired by google safebrowsing update API v4 doesn't contains this hash neither in prefixes nor full hashes. Why `fullHashes:find` detects some url as dangerous and  `threatMatches:find` don't?